# Remove Close (CMD+W) Menu Bar Button Not Working SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, menubar

My problem is simple, i'm trying to remove this button

[image]

found in the File section in the menu bar.

Here is what I've tried:

```
WindowGroup("test") {
    ContentView()
}.commands {
    CommandGroup(replacing: .saveItem) {}
}
```

For some reason this works in a fresh project as well. Here are some other CommandGroups that I am editing for other parts of the app

```
SidebarCommands()

CommandMenu("Launch") {
     ...
}

CommandGroup(replacing: .newItem) { }

CommandGroup(replacing: .toolbar) { }
        
CommandGroup(replacing: .appInfo) {
    Button("About app") {
       openWindow(id: "about")
    }
}

CommandGroup(replacing: .appTermination) {
      ...
}

CommandGroup(after: .appSettings) {
            Section {
                CheckForUpdatesView(updater: updaterController.updater)
                    .environmentObject(networkMonitor)
            }
        }

CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
            Button("Add Item") {
                showAddItem = true
            }
        }
```

If this code even helps, I change the About section of my app to a custom one:

```
Window("About", id: "about") {
            AboutView()
                .background {
                    if aboutWindow == nil {
                        Color.clear.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for:
                                                                                    NSWindow.didBecomeKeyNotification)) { notification in
                            if let aboutWindow = notification.object as? NSWindow {
                                if aboutWindow.title == "About" {
                                    aboutWindow.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.frame(width: 400, height: 250)
        }.windowResizability(.contentSize).windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
```

I've done my research and cannot find any solutions to this problem.

Note: I saw every single post that says to do exactly what I tried, none of them worked, so i'm just creating one here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you have multiple windows. On each window, you have to say to remove the CommandGroup saveItem, here is a example.

```
WindowGroup() {
    ContentView()
}.commands {
    CommandGroup(replacing: .saveItem) {}
}

WindowGroup("Inspector") {
    InspectorView()
}
```

This code won't work, because the Inspector window group does not have the command group being removed, so to fix it, you would do this:

```
WindowGroup("Inspector") {
    InspectorView()
}.commands {
    CommandGroup(replacing: .saveItem) {}
}
```

So in your case add

```
.commands {
    CommandGroup(replacing: .saveItem) {}
}
```

to your About window.